# SQL Server generating 1G dump files

Tags: sql-server, sql, dump

I have a SQL Server generating  large dump (mdmp) files, some of them are 1 GB in size, these are generated daily, sometimes 2 or 3 in a single day. This server is used heavily for PowerBI reports.

Opening the file with WinDbg I get some information which I don't find helpful, among all the content I can highlight these sections:

```
This dump file has an exception of interest stored in it.
The stored exception information can be accessed via .ecxr.
(980.2228): Unknown exception - code 000042ac (first/second chance not available)
```

If I type .ecxr command I get (among many other lines):

```
ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xa
KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x68
```

Tried a google search on these errors but I didn't find anything meaningful

If I click the link to run ***!analyze -V*** I get a stack trace and perhaps I can highlight this:

```
PROCESS_NAME:  RSPowerBI.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0x42ac - <Unable to get error code text>

EXCEPTION_CODE_STR:  42ac
```

Where to go from here? What other things to check?

SQL Server Version

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-GDR) (KB4505224) - 14.0.2027.2 (X64)   Jun 15 2019 00:26:19   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)
```

Full Dump content

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.19041.1 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [E:\Logfiles\SQLDmpr0528.mdmp]
User Mini Dump File with Full Memory: Only application data is available

Symbol search path is: srv*
Executable search path is: 
Windows 8.1 Version 9600 MP (2 procs) Free x64
Product: Server, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS
6.3.9600.18217 (winblue_ltsb.160124-0053)
Machine Name:
Debug session time: Mon Oct 12 07:33:19.000 2020 (UTC - 5:00)
System Uptime: 17 days 14:50:15.803
Process Uptime: 17 days 14:49:41.000
................................................................
................................................................
.....................................
Loading unloaded module list
................................................................
This dump file has an exception of interest stored in it.
The stored exception information can be accessed via .ecxr.
(980.2228): Unknown exception - code 000042ac (first/second chance not available)
For analysis of this file, run !analyze -v
ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xa:
00007ff9`42bd074a c3              ret
0:023> .ecxr
rax=000000ff168ce3f1 rbx=0000000080004005 rcx=0000000000000001
rdx=0000000000000000 rsi=000000fdebb60ba8 rdi=000000ff1214cd20
rip=00007ff93fff7afc rsp=000000ff168ce8d0 rbp=000000ff168cea90
 r8=00007ff938e7be56  r9=0000000000000000 r10=0000000000a5df10
r11=ffffff00e9731bfa r12=000000fdebb5d2d8 r13=0000000000000000
r14=0000000000000000 r15=000000fde7b11b20
iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na pe nc
cs=0033  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000202
KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x68:
00007ff9`3fff7afc 488b8c24c0000000 mov     rcx,qword ptr [rsp+0C0h] ss:000000ff`168ce990=0000110269ef40b6
0:023> .ecxr
rax=000000ff168ce3f1 rbx=0000000080004005 rcx=0000000000000001
rdx=0000000000000000 rsi=000000fdebb60ba8 rdi=000000ff1214cd20
rip=00007ff93fff7afc rsp=000000ff168ce8d0 rbp=000000ff168cea90
 r8=00007ff938e7be56  r9=0000000000000000 r10=0000000000a5df10
r11=ffffff00e9731bfa r12=000000fdebb5d2d8 r13=0000000000000000
r14=0000000000000000 r15=000000fde7b11b20
iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na pe nc
cs=0033  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000202
KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x68:
00007ff9`3fff7afc 488b8c24c0000000 mov     rcx,qword ptr [rsp+0C0h] ss:000000ff`168ce990=0000110269ef40b6
0:023> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Exception Analysis                                   *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for System.ni.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for System.Data.ni.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for System.Net.Http.ni.dll
MethodDesc:   00007ff8d9dc9b78
Method Name:  Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlDumper.Dumper.Dump()
Class:        00007ff8d9dd0680
MethodTable:  00007ff8d9dc9d10
mdToken:      000000000600004c
Module:       00007ff8d9ae4838
IsJitted:     yes
CodeAddr:     00007ff8db84fe20
Transparency: Safe critical
MethodDesc:   00007ff8d982a040
Method Name:  Microsoft.BIServer.Configuration.SqlDumperAdapter.Microsoft.BIServer.Configuration.IDumperAdapter.Dump(Microsoft.BIServer.Configuration.DumpInstructions)
Class:        00007ff8d99c7408
MethodTable:  00007ff8d982a070
mdToken:      0000000006000169
Module:       00007ff8d9829518
IsJitted:     yes
CodeAddr:     00007ff8db84f230
Transparency: Critical
MethodDesc:   00007ff8d982a210
Method Name:  Microsoft.BIServer.Configuration.Dumper.GenerateDump(System.Exception, Boolean)
Class:        00007ff8d99c7530
MethodTable:  00007ff8d982a430
mdToken:      00000000060000b3
Module:       00007ff8d9829518
IsJitted:     yes
CodeAddr:     00007ff8db7cf450
Transparency: Critical
MethodDesc:   00007ff8d9c95638
Method Name:  Microsoft.PowerBI.ReportServer.WebHost.WebApiConfigFactory+WebApiExceptionFilterAttribute.OnException(System.Web.Http.Filters.HttpActionExecutedContext)
Class:        00007ff8d9ca5130
MethodTable:  00007ff8d9c95648
mdToken:      0000000006000083
Module:       00007ff8d9824148
IsJitted:     yes
CodeAddr:     00007ff8db84ecb0
Transparency: Critical
MethodDesc:   00007ff8d9c95520
Method Name:  System.Web.Http.Filters.ExceptionFilterAttribute.OnExceptionAsync(System.Web.Http.Filters.HttpActionExecutedContext, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
Class:        00007ff8d9ca5020
MethodTable:  00007ff8d9c95558
mdToken:      0000000006000568
Module:       00007ff8d9b93cc8
IsJitted:     yes
CodeAddr:     00007ff8db84ec20
Transparency: Critical
MethodDesc:   00007ff8d9e20d20
Method Name:  System.Web.Http.Filters.ExceptionFilterAttribute+<ExecuteExceptionFilterAsyncCore>d__3.MoveNext()
Class:        00007ff8d9e0dd28
MethodTable:  00007ff8d9e20dd0
mdToken:      0000000006000b53
Module:       00007ff8d9b93cc8
IsJitted:     yes
CodeAddr:     00007ff8db84eac0
Transparency: Safe critical
MethodDesc:   00007ff8dbc2fe20
Method Name:  System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[[System.Web.Http.Filters.ExceptionFilterAttribute+<ExecuteExceptionFilterAsyncCore>d__3, System.Web.Http]](<ExecuteExceptionFilterAsyncCore>d__3 ByRef)
Class:        00007ff937a25f98
MethodTable:  00007ff93791d270
mdToken:      0000000006005cf8
Module:       00007ff937871000
IsJitted:     yes
CodeAddr:     00007ff8db84e9d0
Transparency: Safe critical
MethodDesc:   00007ff8d9c95540
Method Name:  System.Web.Http.Filters.ExceptionFilterAttribute.ExecuteExceptionFilterAsyncCore(System.Web.Http.Filters.HttpActionExecutedContext, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
Class:        00007ff8d9ca5020
MethodTable:  00007ff8d9c95558
mdToken:      000000000600056a
Module:       00007ff8d9b93cc8
IsJitted:     yes
CodeAddr:     00007ff8db84e930
Transparency: Critical
MethodDesc:   00007ff8d9c95528
Method Name:  System.Web.Http.Filters.ExceptionFilterAttribute.System.Web.Http.Filters.IExceptionFilter.ExecuteExceptionFilterAsync(System.Web.Http.Filters.HttpActionExecutedContext, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
Class:        00007ff8d9ca5020
MethodTable:  00007ff8d9c95558
mdToken:      0000000006000569
Module:       00007ff8d9b93cc8
IsJitted:     yes
CodeAddr:     00007ff8db84e8c0
Transparency: Critical
MethodDesc:   00007ff8d9e22968
Method Name:  System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult+<ExecuteAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
Class:        00007ff8d9e0e7e8
MethodTable:  00007ff8d9e22a28
mdToken:      0000000006000b97
Module:       00007ff8d9b93cc8
IsJitted:     yes
CodeAddr:     00007ff8d9eedf30
Transparency: Safe critical

KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1

    Key  : Analysis.CPU.Sec
    Value: 104

    Key  : Analysis.DebugAnalysisProvider.CPP
    Value: Create: 8007007e on MY_SERVER

    Key  : Analysis.DebugData
    Value: CreateObject

    Key  : Analysis.DebugModel
    Value: CreateObject

    Key  : Analysis.Elapsed.Sec
    Value: 108

    Key  : Analysis.Memory.CommitPeak.Mb
    Value: 3164

    Key  : Analysis.System
    Value: CreateObject

    Key  : CLR.Engine
    Value: CLR

    Key  : CLR.Version
    Value: 4.0.30319.0

    Key  : Timeline.OS.Boot.DeltaSec
    Value: 1522215

    Key  : Timeline.Process.Start.DeltaSec
    Value: 1522181


NTGLOBALFLAG:  0

PROCESS_BAM_CURRENT_THROTTLED: 0

PROCESS_BAM_PREVIOUS_THROTTLED: 0

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

CONTEXT:  (.ecxr)
rax=000000ff168ce3f1 rbx=0000000080004005 rcx=0000000000000001
rdx=0000000000000000 rsi=000000fdebb60ba8 rdi=000000ff1214cd20
rip=00007ff93fff7afc rsp=000000ff168ce8d0 rbp=000000ff168cea90
 r8=00007ff938e7be56  r9=0000000000000000 r10=0000000000a5df10
r11=ffffff00e9731bfa r12=000000fdebb5d2d8 r13=0000000000000000
r14=0000000000000000 r15=000000fde7b11b20
iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na pe nc
cs=0033  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000202
KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x68:
00007ff9`3fff7afc 488b8c24c0000000 mov     rcx,qword ptr [rsp+0C0h] ss:000000ff`168ce990=0000110269ef40b6
Resetting default scope

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  (.exr -1)
ExceptionAddress: ffffffffda850f6a
   ExceptionCode: 000042ac
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 0

PROCESS_NAME:  RSPowerBI.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0x42ac - <Unable to get error code text>

EXCEPTION_CODE_STR:  42ac

MISSING_CLR_SYMBOL: 0

FAULTING_THREAD:  ffffffff

STACK_TEXT:  
000000ff`168ce8d0 00007ff9`3fff7afc KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x68
000000ff`168ce9b0 00007ff9`22823b40 Microsoft_SqlServer_MgdSqlDumper+0x3b40
000000ff`168ce9f0 00007ff8`db84fe7f unknown!unknown+0x0
000000ff`168ceaa0 00007ff8`db84f33c unknown!unknown+0x0
000000ff`168ceb00 00007ff8`db7cf71f unknown!unknown+0x0
000000ff`168cebb0 00007ff8`db84ecd8 unknown!unknown+0x0
000000ff`168cebe0 00007ff8`db84ec3c unknown!unknown+0x0
000000ff`168cec20 00007ff8`db84eb06 unknown!unknown+0x0
000000ff`168cec60 00007ff8`db84ea50 unknown!unknown+0x0
000000ff`168ced10 00007ff8`db84e9a3 unknown!unknown+0x0
000000ff`168ceda0 00007ff8`db84e8cf unknown!unknown+0x0
000000ff`168cedd0 00007ff8`d9eee22b unknown!unknown+0x0
000000ff`168cee30 00007ff9`37dfdf12 mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal+0x172
000000ff`168cef00 00007ff9`37dfdd95 mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run+0x15
000000ff`168cef30 00007ff9`37e6d00f mscorlib_ni!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.Run+0x6f
000000ff`168cef80 00007ff9`37dfdf12 mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal+0x172
000000ff`168cf050 00007ff9`37dfdd95 mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run+0x15
000000ff`168cf080 00007ff9`37dc9c06 mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem+0x76
000000ff`168cf0c0 00007ff9`37dc8e46 mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch+0x156
000000ff`168cf160 00007ff9`38e76953 clr!CallDescrWorkerInternal+0x83
000000ff`168cf1a0 00007ff9`38e76858 clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+0x4e
000000ff`168cf1e0 00007ff9`38e77118 clr!MethodDescCallSite::CallTargetWorker+0x102
000000ff`168cf2e0 00007ff9`38e7c13a clr!QueueUserWorkItemManagedCallback+0x2a
000000ff`168cf3d0 00007ff9`38e77d10 clr!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchInner+0x40
000000ff`168cf410 00007ff9`38e77c83 clr!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchMiddle+0x6c
000000ff`168cf510 00007ff9`38e77bc2 clr!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchOuter+0x4c
000000ff`168cf580 00007ff9`38e77da7 clr!ManagedThreadBase_FullTransitionWithAD+0x2f
000000ff`168cf5e0 00007ff9`38e7c087 clr!ManagedPerAppDomainTPCount::DispatchWorkItem+0xa4
000000ff`168cf760 00007ff9`38e778d7 clr!ThreadpoolMgr::ExecuteWorkRequest+0x64
000000ff`168cf790 00007ff9`38e777af clr!ThreadpoolMgr::WorkerThreadStart+0xf6
000000ff`168cf830 00007ff9`38e7b5f5 clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+0x8b
000000ff`168cfc70 00007ff9`421f1412 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x22
000000ff`168cfca0 00007ff9`42b554f4 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x34


STACK_COMMAND:  .ecxr ; kb ; ** Pseudo Context ** Pseudo ** Value: d6710bb820 ** ; kb

SYMBOL_NAME:  Microsoft_SqlServer_MgdSqlDumper+3b40

MODULE_NAME: Microsoft_SqlServer_MgdSqlDumper

IMAGE_NAME:  Microsoft.SqlServer.MgdSqlDumper.dll

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  APPLICATION_FAULT_42ac_Microsoft.SqlServer.MgdSqlDumper.dll!Unknown

OS_VERSION:  6.3.9600.18217

BUILDLAB_STR:  winblue_ltsb

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 8.1

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {f1ad8702-1f9a-8cd4-a327-1e8036eaea61}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------
```

Comment: Why do you actually generate dump files? Transfer, backup should be done with backup files, not dump files. Second - what is the problem? I do sql server admin and can not remember the last time I did a dump file. Large database = large dump fiile.

Comment: Maybe you should run a more recent build of SQL Server, you're 22 updates behind.

Comment: @GregAskew Thank you, that's a very helpful advice

Comment: It looks like you're running Power BI Report Server on this server, and that is the faulting application (`PROCESS_NAME:  RSPowerBI.exe`). It's a little confusing because Report Server has roots in SQL Server, but is now a fully independent service. I'd recommend bringing both services current with CUs/updates, then contact support if the issue still happens